# Bootstrap: Sticky navigation bar that becomes fixed to the top after scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is an outdated version of this question on this site, it does not answer my question.

I am trying to create a website using Bootstrap that has a landing page where the cover image / carousel fill the entire browser area, and a navbar is fixed at the bottom. It should not be below the view area, but right at the bottom of the screen. Furthermore, it should be fixed so when the visitor scrolls down the navbar follows upwards, and once it hits the top of the screen it gets stuck and follows down.

I tried with the affix plugin, though I have not been able to figure out how to accomplish the above with it.

Here is a site i stumbled upon that has the layout I am trying to create: http://www.basabots.com/

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of how you can do it. The basics are to have the header first at absolute position and at the bottom. Then you watch for the scroll position of the window and change the header to be fixed position and at the top after the scroll amount is above the window height minus the header height.

```js
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
var headerheight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;

function add_class_on_scroll() {
  header.classList.add("fixed");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
  header.classList.remove("fixed");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;
  if (scrollpos > (windowheight - headerheight)) {
    add_class_on_scroll();
  } else {
    remove_class_on_scroll();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1800px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h3>This is the header</h3>
</div>
```

Fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/c686hnek/1/

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Is it not possible with Bootstrap as it is? It comes with some js such as Affix. Will the above solution be responsive, and maintain the right formatting if I change the window size, or open it on a smaller device? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't used bootstrap lately but if you implement the above solution to your existing bootstrap header it should work just fine. My example was just for a general purpose how to achieve something like you wanted. Hopefully you can get it to work with your bootstrap frame :)